# std::vector internals

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

How is `std::vector` implemented, using what data structure? When I write

```
void f(int n) {
  std::vector<int> v(n);
  ...
}
```

Is the vector `v` allocated on stack?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: `v` is on the stack.  `v[0]` will not be on the stack.  `std::vector` should be defined entirely in the library header files.  Go take a look if you'd like to see how it's implemented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `vector` object will be allocated on the **stack** and will internally contain a pointer to *beginning* of the elements on the **heap**.

Elements on the **heap** give the `vector` class an ability to grow and shrink on demand.

While having the `vector` on the **stack** gives the object the benefit of being destructed when going out of scope.

In regards to your `[]` question, the `vector` class **overloads** the `[]` operator. I would say internally it's **basically** doing something like this when you do `array[1]`:

```
return *(_Myfirst+ (n * elementSize))
```

Where the `vector` keeps track of the start of it's internal heap with `_Myfirst`.

When your `vector` starts to fill up, it will **allocate** more memory for you. A common practice is to *double* the amount of memory needed each time.

**Note** that `vector` inherits from `_Vector_val`, which contains the following members:

```
pointer _Myfirst;   // pointer to beginning of array
pointer _Mylast;    // pointer to current end of sequence
pointer _Myend; // pointer to end of array
_Alty _Alval;   // allocator object for values
```

Comment: Sorry, but this does not make sense to me (the pointer part). I can write `v[1] = 100;`...

Comment: That's because the `vector` class uses operator overloads for `[]`.

Comment: Yes, precise answer is not "bunch of pointers", but only ONE pointer, right?

Comment: Well if you look in the header, `vector` inherits from `_Vector_val`. I've listed it's member above.

Comment: You'll probably find that your `vector` implementation lazily claims the initial batch of memory from the heap upon the first write (e.g. with `push_back` or `operator[]` when constructed with the default constructor.  Whilst you shouldn't be writing beyond the end of the vector ever, this is one case that is guaranteed to result in a SEGV.

Comment: @Marko - Yes it's lazy, `vector` isn't going to _guess_ the amount of space you need why you construct it, that's why you can _reserve_ it. You should **never** be writing past the end of the `vector` because you're using using `push_back()`.

Answer (score 5):

Your `v` is allocated in **automatic memory**. (commonly known as the stack, yes)

The implementation details are not specified, but most commonly it's implemented using a dynamic array which is resized if you attempt to add more elements than the previous allocation can hold.

The standard only specifies the interface (which methods it should have) and execution time boundaries.

Since `vector` is a template, the implementation is visible, so locate your `<vector>` file and start inspecting.

Comment: @James: It depends on the allocator template parameter.  THe default allocator (`std::alloc`) will use `new`, not `malloc`.

Comment: @MooingDuck OK, thanks, but it's only a semantic difference, isn't it?

Comment: In some implementations, the default `operator new` calls `malloc`.  But not always.  Also, `operator new(std::size_t)` never returns a null pointer, and can be replaced by a program.

Comment: @James probably yes (via `new`). But a complementary delete is called when `v` goes out of scope.

Comment: @James actually, it's probably a `new[]` & `delete[]`. Just look in the header.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: No, never. There's almost no use for array-`new` in real-world library C++. It's all allocators and element-wise placement-`new`. (Think about the difference between size and capacity; array-`new` wouldn't make any sense.)

Comment: @KerrekSB Could you please extend your answer? It sounds very interesting but I do not understand it completely.

Comment: @James: It's not very tricky, but it's outside the scope of the question, which is about storage of the control structure, and not about the implementation of the vector. Briefly, you allocate a bunch of memory (using `::operator new` or equivalent), and then you placement-construct the actual vector elements into that storage as needed. Resizing requires exception-safe transactional copying or moving.

Comment: @KerrekSB but you still need to allocate new space when you resize. That's what I was saying.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: `new T[]` would require that capacity equals size always.  Whereas `new char[]` with `new(ptr)T()` doesn't force the size to equal capacity.

Comment: @MooingDuck I still don't get it... doesn't ptr have to point to something valid?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: `new T[N]` allocates an array, which has N live `T` objects, all default constructed, and freeing it will destruct all N.  That means (1) you have to use the default constructor always, and (2) you must always have N live objects in the array, no more, no less, which means you would have to resize for every insert and every delete, and size would always equal capacity.  Whereas placement new can place or erase objects onto a `char` buffer at will.

Comment: @MooingDuck I got that. **But** if you exceed that char buffer's capacity, you still have to re-allocate it... That's what I meant.

Comment: @MooingDuck that's why I said `ptr` has to be valid in my previous comment.

Comment: Oh.  then yes.  The point that Xeo and I was making was that vector uses `new char[N*sizeof(T)]` underneath, and not `new T[N]`

Comment: @MooingDuck I actually never wrote `new T[N]` (that was you), only `new []`. I failed to spot that though. But yeah, we're on the same page... :D

Answer (score 2):

```
void f(int n) {
  std::vector<int> v(n);
  ...
}
```

The vector above has automatic storage duration and is allocated on the stack. However, the data array that the vector manages is allocated on the heap.

The internals of the vector are implementation specific, but a typical implementation will contain 3 pointers; one each to keep track of start of array, size of vector and capacity of vector.

Comment: Is it possible to specify somehow to allocate it on stack, or due to "resizability" it's not possible?

Comment: @James Use `std::array` if you want the array on the stack. Of course, you need to know the size in advance then.

Comment: @Prætorian: The three pointers would most elegantly be "beginning of storage", "end-of-elements" and "end-of-capacity". Don't forget that there's also an allocator object :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB That's what I meant by start, size and capacity, but your terms are clearer. And thanks for mentioning the allocator object, that explains why the VS2010 implementation returns `sizeof` as 16, instead of 12 as I was expecting it to.

Comment: @Prætorian: That's unlikely. What's your platform? Any library implementor worth their salt know how to exploit the empty base optimizations.

Comment: @KerrekSB VS2010 on 32-bit Win7. `vector` derives from `_Vector_val` which contains the allocator object as a member, so no EBO to exploit.

Comment: @Prætorian: That's a shame! :-)